# React-native - undefined is not a function (evaluating navigation.openDrawer()')

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I'm very new to React native. I'm going to share my codes here
App.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Routes from './src/Routes';

export default class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <Routes />
    );
  }
}
```

index.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import App from './App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';
import SideMenu from './src/SideMenu'
import Routes from './src/Routes';

const drawernav = createDrawerNavigator({
  Item1: {
      screen: Routes,
    }
  }, {
    contentComponent: SideMenu,
    drawerWidth: Dimensions.get('window').width - 120,  
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => drawernav);
AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

Routes.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer, createDrawerNavigator, DrawerActions } from 'react-navigation';
import Home from './Home';
import Settings from './Settings';
import SideMenu from './SideMenu';
import { Button, Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

const Nav = createStackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: Home,
    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
      title: "Home",
      headerLeft:(<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()}>
                <Text >Button</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
   ),
  })
 },
  Settings: {
screen: Settings,
navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
  title: "Settings",
})     
  },
});
const Routes = createAppContainer(Nav);
export default Routes;
```

SideNav.js

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import styles from './SideMenu.style';
import {NavigationActions} from 'react-navigation';
import {ScrollView, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import Home from './Home';
import Settings from './Settings';

class SideMenu extends Component {
  navigateToScreen = (route) => () => {
    const navigateAction = NavigationActions.navigate({
      routeName: route
    });
    this.props.navigation.dispatch(navigateAction);
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ScrollView>
          <View>
            <Text style={styles.sectionHeadingStyle}>
              Section 1
            </Text>
            <View style={styles.navSectionStyle}>
              <Text style={styles.navItemStyle} onPress= 
   {this.navigateToScreen('Settings')}>
                  Page1
              </Text>
            </View>
          </View>
          <View>
            <Text style={styles.sectionHeadingStyle}>
              Section 2
            </Text>
            <View style={styles.navSectionStyle}>
              <Text style={styles.navItemStyle} onPress= 
   {this.navigateToScreen('Home')}>
                    Page2
              </Text>
              <Text style={styles.navItemStyle} onPress= 
   {this.navigateToScreen('Settings')}>
                    Page3
              </Text>
            </View>            
          </View>
          <View>
            <Text style={styles.sectionHeadingStyle}>
              Section 3
            </Text>
            <View style={styles.navSectionStyle}>
              <Text style={styles.navItemStyle} onPress= 
   {this.navigateToScreen('Settings')}>
                  Page4
              </Text>
            </View>
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
        <View style={styles.footerContainer}>
          <Text>This is my fixed footer</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

SideMenu.propTypes = {
  navigation: PropTypes.object
};

export default SideMenu;
```

Home.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';

export class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View >
        <Text>This is the home screen</Text>
        <Button onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Settings')} title="Settings"/>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

export default Home
```

When I click the button in the header, I get the error

```
undefined is not a function (evaluating navigation.openDrawer()')
```

I really dont mean to do this but I'm really desperate right now. I've spent two days trying to figure how to make a side menu and I'm really disappointed in this framework. You wont even spend 5 mins to create a side menu in Ionic.
Kindly help on this. Project available on git https://github.com/yinka1255/react.git

Comment: hi, you still have that error or solved it?

Answer (score 1):

The error

```
undefined is not a function (evaluating navigation.openDrawer()')
```

is being thrown because [the `navigation` prop does not have an `openDrawer` method](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html). Instead, you need to use the `dispatch` method and the `DrawerActions` helper:

```
import { DrawerActions } from 'react-navigation'
...
const Nav = createStackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: Home,
    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
      title: "Home",
      headerLeft:(
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer())}>
          <Text>Button</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      ),
    })
  },
```

[`DrawerActions` has three methods](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/drawer-actions.html) that each return dispatchable actions. `openDrawer`, `closeDrawer`, and `toggleDrawer` which will toggle the Drawer state from open to closed and vice versa. Hope that helps!

Comment: Milejczac I've done what you wrote. Now it's not throwing error, but the drawer is not opening

Comment: Hey, its work for me but `toggleDrawer` just work as open NOT Close the drawe!

Answer (score 1):

```
undefined is not a function (evaluating navigation.openDrawer()')
```

`DrawerActions from react-navigation` is no longer available.

use `import {DrawerActions} from '@react-navigation/native';`

```
<TouchableOpacity
              onPress={() => navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer())}
              style={{
                width: 60,
                height: 40,
                padding: 10,
                paddingLeft: 20,
              }}>
              <Icon
                size={20}
                name="bars"
                style={{marginLeft: 2}}
                color="#fff"
              />
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'
import { EvilIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons'
import { useNavigation, DrawerActions } from '@react-navigation/native'
import React from 'react'

const Navbar = () => {

    const navigation = useNavigation()
  return (
    <View>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.toggleDrawer())}>
            <View>
                <EvilIcons name='navicon' color='white' size={40}/>
            </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  )
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It's not the framework, it's you.

You dont need to use app.js as a dummy component, you can directly use the same code of routes.js in your app.js . Wraping a navigator inside a component gives problems.

Second, you are using appregistry twice, you shoul use it once, it its going directyl to App.js wich doesn't have a drawer, and is not using drawernav at all, that's why undefined is not a function, there is no drawer .

index.js [the first file react-native looks into]

```
import { AppRegistry, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';
import { createDrawerNavigator , createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import SideMenu from './src/SideMenu'
import Routes from './src/Routes';

const drawernav = createDrawerNavigator({
  Item1: {
      screen: Routes,
    }
  }, {
    contentComponent: SideMenu,
    drawerWidth: Dimensions.get('window').width - 120,  
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => createAppContainer(drawernav));  //createAppContainer goes in your root navigator, in this case, a drawer
```

routes.js

```
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import Home from './Home';
import Settings from './Settings';
import SideMenu from './SideMenu';
import { Button, Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

const Nav = createStackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: Home,
    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
      title: "Home",
      headerLeft:(<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()}>
                <Text >Button</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
   ),
  })
 },
  Settings: {
    screen: Settings,
    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
    title: "Settings",
  })     
  },
}); 

export default Nav;
```

Also, Since you are just displaying one component in the drawer navigator (Routes), you should not be nesting the screens inside a stacknavigator, just pass it to drawernavigator and the drawernavigator will switch between them

```
const drawernav = createDrawerNavigator({
  Item1: {
      screen: Home,
      screen: Settings,
    }
  }, {
    contentComponent: SideMenu,
    drawerWidth: Dimensions.get('window').width - 120,  
});
```